# how do you refresh ABUnknownPersonViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, addressbook

My problem: I have a ABUnknownPersonViewController which needs to get an image from an online database.  I have implemented an NSSession to download the image.  The thread adds the image to the ABRecordRef then adds it to the ABUnknownPersonViewController.  When the controller is pushed on the stack, it doesn't show the image...therfore sadness ensues.

```
NSString *imageUrl = dict[@"mug"];
__block NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
__block NSData *urlData = nil;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];


NSURLSession *session =
[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig
                              delegate:self
                         delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask =
[session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]

           completionHandler:^(NSURL *location,
                               NSURLResponse *response,
                               NSError *error) {

               urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                   newPerson = controller.displayedPerson;
                   ABPersonSetImageData(newPerson, (__bridge CFDataRef)(urlData), &anError);
                   controller.displayedPerson = newPerson;
                   if(urlData != nil) {
                       NSLog(@"I got here");
                       [self viewWillAppear:YES];
                       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"com.razeware.imagegrabber.imageupdated" object:(__bridge id)(newPerson)];

                   }
               });
           }];
[getImageTask resume];
```

**Oddly enough, if I choose "Create New Contact" the image appears (So, the thread is working?).  If I click cancel on iPhone then the image appears on the ABUnknownPersonViewController.  So, it seems like the controller just needs to be refreshed.  How?
I've tried [[self view] setNeedsDisplay]; //ain't working'

Help please!

Comment: What you are doing is a bit confusing and not so clear, can you add a sample project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
ABRecordRef cannot be updated in a thread.  It must be updated on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

OK - This may not be the best practice. However, since you already have `[self viewWillAppear:YES];` you can try calling `[self viewWillDisappear:NO];` before viewWillAppear. This is likely to refresh the content.

Sourced from [here](http://jomnius.blogspot.in/2010/05/how-to-reload-current-uiviewcontroller.html).

Comment: I would also like to point out the recommended practice of using weak references to self inside blocks. Especially when there are network calls involved, I prefer going for this safety measure.

Comment: Do I need to customize viewWillAppear/Disappear or just make the calls?  If I need to define them...what should be the content?

Comment: I don't think there is any necessity to redefine them - I believe you already have (or inherited) the necessary code in either viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear (I assume this because navigating and returning works fine).If the necessary code is in viewDidAppear then you should also call viewDidAppear after viewWillAppear (It appears it won't be called automatically).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently and got this from somewhere else.  Try adding a dispatch sync after the async to the main queue like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // your image fetch code here
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried GCD, but I have the same problem as with other threading methods.  The image is being downloaded, but after it is applied to the ABRecordRef and set on the ABUnknownPersonViewController...then pushed to the stack, changes I make to he ...PersonViewController don't get applied to the one on the stack.  So, the basic question is: How do you change a property once it has been pushed?